# What is unitarily similar matrices?

Tags: unitarity, dirac-matrices

In one of tasks I met the concept of unitarily similar matrices: in particular, I need to prove that sets $\gamma_{\mu}, -\gamma_{\mu}$ (Dirac gamma matrices) are unitarily similar. I don't know what does it mean, so can someone tell me? Maybe, I need to find some unitary transformation that connects first and second sets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I) Two square matrices $A$ and $B$ are [*similar matrices*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) if they are connected via a relation $$\tag{1}AP~=~PB$$ for some invertible matrix $P$.

II) Two square matrices $A$ and $B$ are *unitarily similar matrices* if $P$ in eq. (1) is a unitary matrix.

Comment: Thank you! So in my case $\hat {U}^{+}\gamma_{\mu}\hat {U} = -\gamma_{\mu}$?

Comment: @Andrew McAddams: Yes.